# jQuery: Get the text value of the previous text node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-parsing

I'm trying to get the titles above the form elements on https://www.plot-generator.org.uk/story. However, these titles are text nodes, and so I'm not sure of how to get them. The website is also formatted with lots of unpredictable line breaks:

```
Title 1
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" name="blah">
<br>
Title 2
<br>
<input type="text" name="blah2">
```

So, how would I get the text `Title 1` from `input[name="blah"]`?

Also, how would I get the text `Title 2` from `input[name="blah2"]`?

I tried using [.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/), but I have no clue how to use it:

```
console.log($("input[name=blah]").prev($(this).contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3
})).text())
```

Comment: why not `$("input[type=text]")`? That gets them all. Avoid depending on ordering and other fickle characteristics.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I don't want to get the input text node, I want to get the actual text above it, for example 'Blah' and 'Blah 2'. Sorry, I updated my post to make this more clear.

Comment: OK, based on the structure of that site, you need to make a lot of assumptions. It doesn't use labels or anything. This is not as much about `next`/`prev` as much as about getting text _between_ inputs.

Comment: can you put the text in some div , class or id

Comment: @SagarBhattacharya I don't own that website, so unfortunately there's nothing I can change about the way they formatted it.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I don't think there are any instances where I need the text in between two inputs. I just want to find the previous text node, only one.

Comment: But what if there are more what if you have an `<em>` inside of a `<span>` that comprises the input?

Comment: @AluanHaddad I suppose this could happen, but I'm just looking for an answer in the context of this website, where the text nodes are on the same level as the input nodes, with nothing being inside anything else.

Comment: Make an array of all elements. For each input find the node before it and get its text.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I am already using a loop for each input element: `$("form input, form select").each(function() {` The problem is that as I said, the text node isn't always directly before the previous node. There can be unpredictable line breaks (`<br>`).

Comment: You can't call [`prev`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) like that, it makes no sense.

Comment: Why not write a function that gets the previous node until it finds one that is not empty.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I know it makes no sense. I have no clue how to use it properly. I was hoping a function could be a selector but I guess not. The function idea would be great, but I don't know how I could do that. I'm very bad at jQuery, as you can tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use following approach. Of course, it could be generaliazed/optimized, but it should work:

```
var list = $("input[name=blah]").parent()[0].childNodes;
var input1 = null, input2 = null, value, i1Value = null, i2Value = null;
for(var i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i --) {
  if(list[i].nodeName === 'INPUT') {
    if(list[i].name === 'blah') {
      input1 = i;
    }
    else if(list[i].name === 'blah2') {
      input2 = i;
    }
    continue;
  }
  if(list[i].nodeType === 3) { // text node
    value = list[i].nodeValue.trim(); // to ignore the gaps
    if(value) {
      if(input1 !== null && i1Value === null) {
        i1Value = value;
      }
      if(input2 !== null && i2Value === null) {
        i2Value = value;
      }
    }
  }
  if(i1Value !== null && i2Value !== null) {
    break;
  }
}
console.log(i1Value); // Title 1
console.log(i2Value); // Title 2
```

Answer (score -1):

could you try wrap that titles on predictible tags, like spans or label?
and maybe do like this
`$('input').prev('span')`

Comment: I don't own that website, so unfortunately there's nothing I can change about the way they formatted it.